# Creating Typemap for Overloaded Function in SWIG

Tags: python, swig, typechecking

I am converting a C++ program to Python using SWIG. Since I am using overloaded functions, I have to create a typemap, and specifically, I have to use typechecks for the functions so that it knows which function to use depending on the parameters. There is little to no documentation on the SWIG website on how to create typechecks for `vector <vector <string> >`, `vector <vector <double> >`, or Model types. I visited their [GitHub page](https://github.com/swig/swig/blob/master/Lib/tcl/std_vector.i) which provides some documentation for the vector type, but none of it seemed relevant to my case.

```
void foo(vector <vector <string> > &input, Model *myModel,vector <vector <vector <double> > > &output)


void foo(vector <vector <vector <FS> > > &input, Model *myModel,vector <vector <vector <double> > > &output)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Cython instead of SWIG.

It is specifically designed for writing Python native code extensions, with mappings for C/C++ external code being quite easy to write.

For the above example, a Cython definition file (`.pxd`) can be written:

```
cdef extern from "Foo.h":
    cppclass Model:
        pass
    void foo(vector[string], Model*, vector[vector[double]])
    void foo(vector[vector[FS]], Model*, vector[vector[vector[double]]], Model*)
```

Cython implementation code can then `cimport` from the `.pxd` file and use the C++ functions directly.

See [documentation for more C++ interfacing examples](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#overloading) and [extension types](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html) for implementation code examples.

Comment: Isn't Cython used with code that is originally written in Python? My code is originally written in C++ and I am trying to have a Python performance with it so I am able to import the modules.

Comment: @lucy - No, Cython is an extended language for writing native code extensions for Python. One of its main features is integration with external C/C++ (and fortran) code, per example above. That is exactly your use case.